# Is it possible to determine the exact css image filters that have been applied to an image if all I have are the original and resulting jpeg's?

Tags: css, image, filter

I'm trying to reverse a series of css filters that are being applied to an image. The work is being done by server side js so all I have access to are the original jpeg and the resulting image, but i know that it is a combination of opacity and css filters (blur, brightness, contrast, drop-shadow, grayscale, hue-rotate, invert, opacity, saturate, and/or sepia). Is there any method or tool to find out without access to the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is its called Developer Tools if your using a chrome browser press the `F12 key` or right click on the image in the browser and select `inspect element` [see also...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Then on most browsers:
Ctrl + Shift + I,

Except:

Internet Explorer. F12

Mac OS X. ⌘ + ⌥ + I

Comment: Sorry, when i said "the work is being done by server side js" i meant that all that is loaded into the site is the finished image url... the filters are not being applied by css so there is nothing to inspect.

Comment: its not a website, its a closed source web app - plex, so unfortunately not, but if theres anything you think i could look for I'm open to suggestions, but im certain the js is being done server side so there won't be any way to break down what's happening in dev tools unfortunately.

Comment: @leram84 if the work/effects was truly done sever side then there is no way to reverse such effects unless the developer is kind enough to share his code with you.

Comment: but look in to Photoshop and other imaging software you maybe able to get something.

Comment: thats what i was expecting... I was mostly wondering if there might be some way to do a diff check on 2 images to reverse the filters. Seemed unlikely, but SO's surprised me too many times to take anything for granted :)